# How to mute sound just on Instagram stories?

Tags: audio, instagram

I have an Android smartphone. I wish to mute sound on Instagram stories, which can be achieved easily by using the volume buttons.

However, in that case I need to unmute sound when I want to watch a video on YouTube or listen to a voice message on WhatsApp etc. and it's very annoying.

I want my sound to remain unmuted, but to automatically mute when I open Instagram stories without me having to do this manually.

How can this be achieved?

Edit: I'm obviously thinking about other people's stories, I wish to mute sound while watching other people's stories. It's fairly easy to mute sound when I am uploading my own story and this question is not about that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're fine with muting *all* sound whenever Instagram is launched, you can use an automation app on Android to mute the volume when it detects that Instagram is opened.
Similarly the automation app can detect when Instagram is closed and reset the volume to the previous level or to a pre-set level.

There are many automation app's available, e.g.:

- [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)
- [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)
- [Rulebot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.kfsoft.autotask)
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

I've experience with MacroDroid only. I'll outline the steps below to mute the sound when Instagram is launched. Unmuting it when Instagram is closed is left as an exercise to the reader.

1. Create a new macro
2. For the **trigger** set: `Application Launched/Closed` -> `Application Launched` -> `Instagram`
3. For the **action** set: `Volume Change` -> `Media / Music` -> `Slider value: 0%`
4. For simplicity you can leave the **condition** empty. However, you could for example set a condition that checks whether a headphone is connected and only mute when that's not the case.

Other enhancements would be to store the [volume level before muting](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/macrodroid/get-volume-levels-t4709.html#p17187) such that you can restore that level when unmuting.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Samsung phone, so I use sound assistant to mute Instagram volume.
I only turn it on when I see something interesting.

If you are not using a Samsung, a good alternative I've found is
Volume Manager:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hp.volume

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is sound assistant? My Samsung doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @JonPeltier You probably figured this out by now, but if anybody else sees this, the app is called SoundAssistant and you can find it in the Galaxy Store (i.e. not Google Play Store), and I think you need a Samsung account to download it. In that app there's an option to set individual app volumes. Just add Instagram at set volume to zero.